# MYSQL : Date_format(dateVariable,'%d/%m/%Y') in mysql is giving me string as output where sorting is not working in WorkBench

Tags: mysql

I have 'DateTime' field in MySQL where I want to convert it to DD/MM/YYYY.
Using 'date_format' function in mysql.
But the issue is..... after converting, output is string format not as date format. Because of that sorting fails in WorkBench.

Sample Query :

```
Select date_format(createdDate,'%d/%m/%Y') as created
from OrderTable
Order BY created;
```

Please let me know, if there is any solution.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: But your query is not sorting since there is no order by clause , also order is a reserved word and should be enclosed in backticks..

Comment: Eventhough I have given Order By clause, the result is same i.e., inappropriate sequence

Comment: Sort by original column: `Select date_format(createdDate,'%d/%m/%Y') as created from OrderTable Order BY createdDate;` PS. *after converting, output is string format not as date format* You asked to convert your data to string.. function did.. why you're surprised?

Comment: Need sorting on alias column!!!!!!! Any alternate way to achieve that ??

Comment: Query is alpha ordering as expected see https://dbfiddle.uk/_8asZLpX ie you get all day 01 , day 02 etc grouped and perhaps that's what you want , if you want to order by date order by original column -see second query in fiddle.